# I'm using Cordova in Visual Studio. Can I access my gmail from my app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, email

I want my mobile app to access my gmail and send me a notification in my app about
my new emails. If possible it should be able to read important keywords.

Another question: Can I integrate gmail in my app?

Comment: Nope. Not with your knowledge.  Read more about Xposed, Decompiling, etc...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will get better responses if you ask questions the right way, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using the plugin https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus in the success call back you can get all things

Comment: do you know how will i use my backend with sqlite as cordova does not support php.